# Install powershell modules for Azure Functions not working

Tags: azure, powershell, module, azure-functions

I'm trying to use dependency feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management) but i can't get them working. I added few module (O365, ITGlue modules etc.). I tried to restart function app after changing requirements.psd1 but still nothing. I don't see any error in logs regarding dependencies.
What I'm missing here?

[See requirements.psd1 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7TAT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first check would be to ensure that `managedDependency` property is set to `true` in your function's `host.json` file:

```
{
  "managedDependency": {
          "enabled": true
       }
}
```

Restart the app after updating the `requirements.psd1` file with the modules you need. You can notice the updates being processed in the logs:

[image: Logs]

If you want to verify the installation, you can go to the Kudu site for your app, and navigate to the path `D:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\<id>\` and find them listed:

[image: Kudu]

Another simple way of verifying the same would be to tweak the function to list it. For example:

```sh
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    # Body = $body
    Body = $(Get-Module -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name, Path)
})
```

Calling your function should now list all the installed dependencies:
[image: Example]

Do note that Managed dependencies currently don't support modules that require the user to accept a license, either by accepting the license interactively, or by providing `-AcceptLicense` switch when invoking `Install-Module`. Also make sure that the runtime can access the PowerShell Gallery URL by adjusting any required firewall rules.

Comment: Thank you Bhargavi for detailed answer. I was missing -usewindowspowershell when I imported modules as far as I can remember. (I asked this questions some time ago :) )

Comment: I have tried in same way its NOT able to download dependent libraries. I have verified in D:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\<id>\ also I have tried with {'Az' : '4.*'} and {'Az' : '5.*'}.  In Kudu I am not able to see any Get-PackageSource and Get-PSRepository