# Azure Function PowerShell Module Not Loading From Requirements.psd1 File

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

We are wanting to utilize the Microsoft Graph through Azure Functions and are receiving errors.

```
[Error]   ERROR: The term 'Connect-MgGraph' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I've tried different module calls in the requirements.psd1 file but it seems to just ignore them.

```
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. Uncomment the next line and replace the MAJOR_VERSION, e.g., 'Az' = '5.*'
    # 'Az' = '10.*'
    'Az.Accounts' = '2.5.4'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication' = '2.*'

}
```

My host.json file has managedDependency set to true.

Comment: I've had similar issues previously, but can't recall how I resolved it... I'd seen that the "host.json"'s `managedDependency` seemed to have some people using `"enabled": true` and some `"Enabled": true` so there may be a case sensitivity issue?  I think I ended up running `get-module -all -listavailable`, `import-module`, and `install-module` with debugging enabled to capture the output / to show what was loaded at various stages and to see if any errors were generated when loading the modules.  Hope that's some help?  If I manage to recall the exact fix I found I'll update...

Comment: I'm able to view all the modules installed and none of the ones I'm declaring in the requirements.psd1 file are showing up. I tried running Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser in the run.ps1 file but it came back with the generic error:

2023-11-08T19:06:08Z   [Error]   ERROR: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Microsoft.Graph'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.

Comment: Odd; that implies the PSGallery isn't configured. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/995191/install-module-microsoft-graph-powershell-module says how to fix; but I'd be surprised if that's the issue in Azure Functions.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64315886/361842 mentions restarting the app; maybe that's all that's needed?

Comment: Neither option got me to the finish line. I'll keep troubleshooting but appreciate the tips here.

Answer (score 0):

- Install `Microsoft.Graph` module manually in Terminal.
- Import `Microsoft.Graph` Module in the run.ps1:

```
Import-Module  -Name Microsoft.Graph
```

(or)

add `Microsoft.Graph` module in the **requirements.ps1**:

```
@{
'Microsoft.Graph'  =  '2.2.0'
}
```

- Run `Connect-MgGraph` in the run.ps1 to connect to Microsoft graph

```
Connect-MgGraph
```

---

- I am running the above-mentioned commands in the Http Trigger Azure function:

**My Code Snippet:**

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Importing the Microsoft.Graph Module
Import-Module  -Name Microsoft.Graph

# Connecting to the the Microsoft Graph
Connect-MgGraph

Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

- **Redirected to Authentication page** when running the Azure function:

[image]

[image]

**Console Response:**

[image]